# PhoneGap 2.3.0 + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm currently developing an hybrid app using the Salesforce-Mobile-SDK. In order to fulfill some offline requirements which are part of the project I need to access some sort of database on the device and my first pick is SQLite.

Is there any PhoneGap 2.3.0 compatible plugin to open and perform CRUD operations on a SQLite database?

I've already googled a lot this afternoon and i've found somw interesting plugins but they refer to other PhoneGap versions and i'm afraid i'm constrained to v 2.3.0.

Thank you.
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a plugin for this as support for webSQL(sqlite) is included in PhoneGap 2.3.0.

You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database)

Example:

```
var db = window.openDatabase('appdb','1.0','AppDB',5000000);

db.transaction(function(tx){
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (itemid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, otherField, someField)');
}, errorCallback, successCallback));
```

Comment: Thank You @Dawson Loudon , in fact I got confused during my poor search on Google, do you know if there are capacity limits on the DB created, I don't need a lot of space but i've heard about 5 megabytes of limitation which might not be enough. TY!

Comment: From my experience, iOS is more strict about this than Android. I have created some very data heavy apps and have never had an issue. I think the last one I made held around 25mb of data and I never reached any limit. I have my db definition set to 50mb and it works on both platforms, so I am not 100% sure about the 5mb that people claim exists.